# Copy file on to HDFS Hadoop environment using C#

Tags: c#, .net, hadoop, hdfs, webhdfs

How do I connect to **HDFS(on Hortonworks/EC2 data platform)** and copy a file from Local system using a .net application.?
Is using the **WebHDFS** the right approach to connect to HDFS via .net application? referred below link[https://hadoopsdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebHDFS%20Client&referringTitle=Home].
Please let me know what is the right way to connect to HDFS using C#.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect ot HDFS as follows.

```
   Hadoop.Connect().StorageSystem.CopyFromLocal(sourcePath, "/FolderPath");
```

Use Microsoft .NET Map Reduce API for Hadoop.

[image]